# what are the permissions command to be implemented when accessing the private key in SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl

I have got the private key located at: /etc/ssl/private/PRIVATEKEY.key

I ran nginx -t and the configuration is correct. So I ran from root promt:

```
systemctl reload nginx
```

but I got this error:

```
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate key "/etc/ssl/private/PRIVATEKEY.key": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed (SSL: error:1>
Jan 29 14:00:33 vmi1520937 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
```

I imagine it would have to be a permissions error. The PRIVATEKEY.key is the key I generated when I created the csr file, this is in accordance with the instructions.

I ran

```
sudo chmod 600 PRIVATEKEY.key
sudo chown root:root PRIVATEKEY.key
```

but I still get the error

UPDATE:
It seems that the private key I generated is password protected but I am baffled because what can I do now? I created it like this,

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout PRIVATEKEY.key -out MYCSR.csr
```

and then just uploaded it to /etc/ssl/private but nginx can't read it
yes, I know the password I was asked when building the files, but I don't know now how to nginx is supposed to use it.

Comment: What makes you think it’s a permission error? Have you considered looking up SSL error 1?

Comment: (0) not programming or development (1) it doesn't have to be permissions and in fact it can't be; the file is opened _before_ calling `PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey` (2) the untruncated error message will probably help; try `journalctl --no-pager -n10` (or other suitable number) and if the error wasn't recent (i.e. isn't near the end of the log) add `-unginx`  (@user207421: that's not error 1, that's a truncation of OpenSSL's format which should be error:8digithex:module:function:reason:maybe more)

Comment: It seems that the private key I generated is password protected but I am baffled because what can I do now? I created it like this, openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout PRIVATEKEY.key -out MYCSR.csr and then just uploaded it to /etc/ssl/private but nginx can't read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I thank all of those who posted positive comments which added good insight and finally lead to the solution. The problem was that the private key was password protected (when you generate it, it asks you for one) but the caveat is that nginx cannot call you on your mobile to ask you for the password, so you have to remove that password internally:

This is what you do:

```
root@vmi:/etc/nginx/ssl# cp PRIVATEKEY.key PRIVATEKEY.key.pw
root@vmi:/etc/nginx/ssl# openssl rsa -in PRIVATEKEY.key.pw -out PRIVATEKEY.key
Enter pass phrase for PRIVATEKEY.key.pw:
writing RSA key
```

Comment: You can use `rsa` or `pkey` to decrypt an encrypted private key; alternatively you could have created it with `req -newkey rsa:$bits -keyout $file -nodes ...` (the spelling remains `-nodes` even though the encryption hasn't been DES for decades). Alternatively [**nginx CAN be given the password**](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_password_file)

Comment: yes, I posted my answer yesterday that I can only accept tomorrow, but it goes as you say, namely: root@vmi:/etc/nginx/ssl# cp PRIVATEKEY.key PRIVATEKEY.key.pw
root@vmi:/etc/nginx/ssl# openssl rsa -in PRIVATEKEY.key.pw -out PRIVATEKEY.key
Enter pass phrase for PRIVATEKEY.key.pw:
writing RSA key